While sending mail, the body of the mail lines are getting merged in unix
I have to send an email from my development server, the mail body is having some 20 lines. But Few lines are getting merged.
I have tried no of scenarios (used mailx,mail & sendmail also) to avoid this, but still the lines in body mail are getting merged.
$ cat check.txt  
Company*+ ! 1000000001!: Global Operations  
Last Name* ! 1000000018!: Global Operations  
First Name* ! 1000000019!:Generic 

command used to send this mail:
mailx -s "FAILURE" < check.txt "abc@gmail.com"

Received Output in mail:
Company*+ ! 1000000001!: Global Operations Last Name* ! 1000000018!: Global Operations First Name* ! 1000000019!:Generic

Let me know if I am doing any wrong in the code.

Unfortunately, when sending plain text emails, some email clients at the receiving end will assume that they can re-wrap the lines as they see fit. There is really no standard way to prevent this.

@telcoM well, you can send the text file as attachment instead of as message body, and handle the attachment on your own instead of asking the mail client to give you the plain text message body. (note that mailx is especially ill-suited for this, because it will auto-convert text attachments… sigh.)

What's probably happening is on your server you are using unix/linux line breaks.  On the client it is probably using windows line breaks.
One thing to try would be to convert the file to windows line breaks using something like unix2dos.
e.g. (assuming you are on a Debian based linux)
sudo apt install dos2unix
unix2dos check.txt 
mailx -s "FAILURE" < check.txt "abc@gmail.com"

